# graph satellite images from an xarray dataset

Tags: python-xarray

I want to graph some satellite images from an xarray dataset. My data has this structure

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:                      (time: 1, y_geostationary: 4176,
                                  x_geostationary: 5548, variable: 1)
Coordinates:
  * time                         (time) datetime64[ns] 2021-01-01
  * variable                     (variable) <U3 'HRV'
  * x_geostationary              (x_geostationary) float64 -2.733e+06 ... 2.8...
  * y_geostationary              (y_geostationary) float64 1.395e+06 ... 5.57...
Data variables:
    data                         (time, y_geostationary, x_geostationary, variable) float16 dask.array<chunksize=(1, 100, 100, 1), meta=np.ndarray>
    x_geostationary_coordinates  (time, x_geostationary) float64 dask.array<chunksize=(1, 5548), meta=np.ndarray>
    y_geostationary_coordinates  (time, y_geostationary) float64 dask.array<chunksize=(1, 4176), meta=np.ndarray>
```

I tried to do this.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Squeeze the dimensions of the satellite image
image = df['data'].squeeze()

# Plot the satellite image
plt.imshow(image, origin='lower')
plt.show()
```

But I don't think it's working correctly since the output is just a grey almost square.

I'm not sure of how to provide sample data for this, but I was hoping that someone could point me in the right direction to graph the images in general.

Comment: What are the values of image.min(), image.max() ? More generally, have you tried to plo the histogram of te data ? Through plt.hist(image.ravel()) for instance ?

Comment: the output for the min and max is `<xarray.DataArray 'data' ()>
array(0.000422, dtype=float16)
Coordinates:
    time      datetime64[ns] 2021-01-01
    variable  <U3 'HRV'
<xarray.DataArray 'data' ()>
array(0.02324, dtype=float16)
Coordinates:
    time      datetime64[ns] 2021-01-01
    variable  <U3 'HRV'. I'm not familiar with this type of data, so I don't know if the output is correct. The histogram has a large peek in the center, but I'm not sure what the implications of that are

Comment: Alright, so no problem with the data itself. So what would a slight variation of your code would give : plt.pcolormesh(image.values)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are 4 dimensions, and two of them are singular, you can directly do the following
e.g.,

```
ds = xr.open_dataset("file.nc")

ds['data'].plot(x='x_geostationary', y='y_geostationary')
```

or you can also do something like

```
ds['data'].isel(time=0, variable=0).plot(x='x_geostationary', y='y_geostationary')
```